# Can't seem to removeEventListener after adding addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to add a blur event to some form elements which will run some code for me. After the initial blur, I'm trying to remove the listener from that element so that it doesn't fire again.

The onblur event works fine, but for some reason the eventListener.remove never seems to fire, so blur doesn't get removed. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATED based on lincolnk's comments, but still NOT working in IE:

```
(function() {
var els = [document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
                    document.getElementsByTagName('select')],

        eventListener = {
            add: function(el, ev, fn) {
              if (window.addEventListener)  { // Standard
                el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
              } else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
                var iefn = function() { fn.call(el) };
                el.attachEvent('on' + ev, iefn)
              } else { return false };
            },

            remove: function(el, ev, fn) {
              if (window.removeEventListener)  { // Standard
                el.removeEventListener(ev, fn, false)
              } else if (window.detachEvent) { // IE
                var iefn = function() { fn.call(el) };
                el.detachEvent('on' + ev, iefn)
              } else { return false };
            }
        },

        wtFormTracker = function() {
            console.log(this.name);
            eventListener.remove(this, 'blur', wtFormTracker);
        };

for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
    for (var y = 0, z = els[i].length; y < z; y++) {
        eventListener.add(els[i][y], 'blur', wtFormTracker);
    }
}
})();
```

UPDATE: Fully operational in all browsers

```
(function() {
var els = [document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
                    document.getElementsByTagName('select')],

        eventListener = {
            add: function(el, ev, fn) {
              if (window.addEventListener)  { // Standard
                el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
              } else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
                el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn)
              } else { return false };
            },

            remove: function(el, ev, fn) {
              if (window.removeEventListener)  { // Standard
                el.removeEventListener(ev, fn, false)
              } else if (window.detachEvent) { // IE
                el.detachEvent('on' + ev, fn)
              } else { return false };
            }
        },

        wtFormTracker = function(el) {
            var target = el.target || el.srcElement;
            console.log("'WT.ti','title-of-page','WT.ac', " + target.name);
            eventListener.remove(target, 'blur', wtFormTracker);
        };

for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
    for (var y = 0, z = els[i].length; y < z; y++) {
        eventListener.add(els[i][y], 'blur', wtFormTracker);
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to remove `test2` as a handler of `blur` but you have not assigned it anywhere in this script. I'm also guessing the use of `this` within `test1` is pointing to `window` which is probably not what you want.

```
test1: function(e) {
            console.log('add');
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            eventListener.remove(target , 'blur', wtHelper.test1);  // probably?
        },
```

also if you're viewing this in IE, you are creating a brand new function for `attachEvent` and then you create another brand new function for `detachEvent` and you're not going to get anywhere like that. there's nothing wrong with providing your original `fn` parameter to `attachEvent/detachEvent` just like you do for `addEventListener`.

Comment: i posted the updated code...is this what you were referring to for IE?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to remove the wtHelper.test2 function, which was never defined as listener for 'blur' event.
You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
    wtHelper = {
        test1: function() {
            console.log('add');
            wtHelper.test2();
        },

        test2: function() {
            console.log('remove');
            eventListener.remove(this, 'blur', wtHelper.test1);
        }
    };
```